# NextJS Image component not responding to my inline css inside it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, nextjs-image

Why isn't styling inside the Image component in NextJS not allowing me to manipulate my image.
Am I missing something?

```
<Image className={styles.bg}
        style={{ transform: `translateY(${offset * 0.5}px)` }}
        src="/../public/bg.jpg"
        // width={2049}
        // height={2049}
        // objectFit="cover"
        layout="fill"
        quality={100}
      />
```

Comment: <Image className={styles.bg}
style={{ transform: `translateY(${offset * 0.5}px)` }}
        src="/../public/bg.jpg"
        // width={2049}
        // height={2049}
        // objectFit="cover"
        layout="fill"
        quality={100}
      />

Answer (score 1):

If Next.js version is less than 12.1.1, this will not work. Onwards there is support for canonical `style` [prop](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-12-2#nextfutureimage-component-experimental). With the `style` prop in support for props like `layout`, `objectFit`, and `objectPosition` is removed in Next.js 13.

Answer (score 0):

Other properties on the  component will be passed to the underlying img element with the exception of the following:

style. Use className instead.

Comment: OP asked for styling, question is not about loading image, or how address it.

Comment: Can I see your the Image component?

Comment: OP is using [Next.js built-in image component](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image).

Answer (score 0):

NextJs v12.1.1 added the `style` prop to next/image.

Comment: Kinda late buddy 

Answer (score 0):

next 12 does not support styling the image tag directly, but the way to go about this is to put the image tag inside a div container, which we will apply the styling to, here is a sample

```
<div className={style.styling}>
   <Image src={image.url} width={100} height={100} />
</div>
```